# error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, opensuse, xbox360

I'm trying to use an xbox360 controller as a joystick in openSUSE 11.2. When attempting to compile xboxdrv (http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/) I get the following errors:

```
g++ -o src/xbox_controller.o -c -g -O2 -Wall -ansi -pedantic src/xbox_controller.cpp
In file included from src/xbox_controller.hpp:23,
                 from src/xbox_controller.cpp:24:
src/xbox_generic_controller.hpp:30: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
src/xbox_generic_controller.hpp:30: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
src/xbox_generic_controller.hpp:31: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
In file included from src/xbox_controller.cpp:24:
src/xbox_controller.hpp:38: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
src/xbox_controller.hpp:38: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
src/xbox_controller.hpp:39: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
src/xbox_controller.cpp:54: error: variable or field 'set_rumble' declared void
src/xbox_controller.cpp:54: error: 'uint8_t' was not declared in this scope
src/xbox_controller.cpp:54: error: 'uint8_t' was not declared in this scope
scons: *** [src/xbox_controller.o] Error 1
```

scons: building terminated because of errors.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: But don't actually post it ;) It'll get migrated automatically when enough high rep users/moderators vote for it to be migrated.

Comment: I believe `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` will also provide a definition for `uint8_t`.

Comment: @jww no, -std=c++11 or -std=gun++11 can't provide the definitions. These definitions are in cstdint header

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6013245/16217248

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit src/xbox_controller.hpp, add missing `#include <stdint.h>` to it (somewhere near the beginning).