# Are types like uint32, int32, uint64, int64 defined in any stdlib header?

Tags: c, libc

I often see source code using types like uint32, uint64 and I wonder if they should be defined by the programmer in the application code or if they are defined in a standard lib header.

What's the best way to have these types on my application source code?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The C99 [`stdint.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html) defines these:

- `int8_t`
- `int16_t`
- `int32_t`
- `uint8_t`
- `uint16_t`
- `uint32_t`

And, if the architecture supports them:

- `int64_t`
- `uint64_t`

There are various other integer typedefs in `stdint.h` as well.

If you're stuck without a C99 environment then you should probably supply your own typedefs and use the C99 ones anyway.

The `uint32` and `uint64` (i.e. without the `_t` suffix) are probably application specific.

Comment: This answer is wrong. All of the above are only available if an exact width type of that size (no padding) exists in the implementation. Even if not, however, the types `int_leastNN_t` and `uint_leastNN_t` for `NN` 8, 16, 32, and 64 **must always exist**. C99 does not allow implementations without an integer type of at least 64 bits, since `long long` is required to be at least that large.

Comment: @R..: Would it be accurate to say "POSIX stdint.h" rather than "C99 stdint.h"?

Comment: POSIX `stdint.h` requires them all.

Comment: @R.., Can you please edit this answer for correctness? It took me a bit to parse the combination of current content and your comments.

Comment: SDL define alias such alias `typedef uint32_t Uint32;` in include/SDL_stdinc.h (if you are SDL user)

Comment: what is the `_t` suffix mean for?

Comment: @RFC7676 It is a common notation in some circles for "type".

Answer (score 16):

Those integer types are all defined in `stdint.h`

Comment: Isn't `stdint.h` implementation-specific? Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911035/uint32-int16-and-the-like-are-they-standard-c) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734802/fixed-width-integers-in-c)

Comment: Looking at the file I found "ISO C99: 7.18 Integer types <stdint.h>" in the comments. I suppose you get `stdint.h` if you're respecting the C99 standard.

Comment: I'm not finding any of them in `stdint.h`. This returns 0 hits: `grep uint32 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stdint.h | grep -v uint32_t`.

Comment: @jww: In my case, that file contains `#include "stdint-gcc.h"`, and grepping *that* file yields the definitions.

Comment: @VictorZamanian - I'm still not finding them `stdint-gcc.h`. There is a `typedef __UINT32_TYPE__ uint32_t`; but nothing for `uint32`. The same applies to `uint8`, `uint16` and `uint64` as well (and the signed variants).

Comment: @jww yeah, they don't exist. The only ones that are standard and that should be defined there are the ones with the `_t` suffix, as listed in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C99 just include `stdint.h`. BTW, the 64bit types are there iff the processor supports them.

Comment: Please cite something in this regard.

Comment: x86 does not support 64-bit math but has 64-bit types.

Comment: Yes it does. It supports 32-bit x 32-bit -> 64-bit multiplication, 64-bit / 32-bit -> 32-bit quotient & 32-bit remainder division, as well as having add with carry and subtract with borrow instructions. It was built to be able to perform 64-bit arithmetic, if only because the 8086 needed to be able to do 32-bit arithmetic.

Comment: There is also a `uint128_t` if `__SIZEOF_INT128__` is defined to 16 or greater (GCC and compatibles). Its available on x86_64/amd64 machines, but the processor does not natively support it. Only Cray's have that register size, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

The questioner actually asked about int16 (etc) rather than (ugly) int16_t (etc).

There are no standard headers - nor any in Linux's /usr/include/ folder that define them without the "_t".

Comment: They said 'like' uint32 ... not 'exactly the same as' uint32 ...