# Weird error in R when importing (64-bit) integer with many digits

Tags: r, precision, digits, read.csv

I am importing a csv that has a single column which contains very long integers (for example: 2121020101132507598)

> a<-read.csv('temp.csv',as.is=T)

When I import these integers as strings they come through correctly, but when imported as integers the last few digits are changed. I have no idea what is going on...

> 1   "4031320121153001444"  4031320121153001472
>   2   "4113020071082679601"  4113020071082679808
>   3   "4073020091116779570"  4073020091116779520
>   4   "2081720101128577687"  2081720101128577792
>   5   "4041720081087539887"  4041720081087539712
>   6   "4011120071074301496"  4011120071074301440
>   7   "4021520051054304372"  4021520051054304256
>   8   "4082520061068996911"  4082520061068997120
>   9   "4082620101129165548"  4082620101129165312

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have noted, you can't represent integers that large.  But R isn't reading those values into integers, it's reading them into double precision numerics.

Double precision can only represent numbers to ~16 places accurately, which is why you see your numbers rounded after 16 places.  See the [gmp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html), [Rmpfr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html), and [int64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/index.html) packages for potential solutions.  Though I don't see a function to read from a file in any of them, maybe you could cook something up by looking at their sources.

UPDATE:
Here's how you can get your file into an `int64` object:

```
# This assumes your numbers are the only column in the file
# Read them in however, just ensure they're read in as character
a <- scan("temp.csv", what="")
ia <- as.int64(a)
```

Answer (score 8):

R's maximum intger value is about 2E9. As @Joshua mentions in another answer, one of the potential solutions is the int64 package.

Import the values as character instead. Then convert to type [int64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64).

```
require(int64)
a <- read.csv('temp.csv', colClasses = 'character', header=FALSE)[[1]]
a <- as.int64(a)
print(a)
[1] 4031320121153001444 4113020071082679601 4073020091116779570
[4] 2081720101128577687 4041720081087539887 4011120071074301496
[7] 4021520051054304372 4082520061068996911 4082620101129165548
```

Comment: These days you can simply do `read.csv(..., colClasses=c('integer64',...))` and read it directly. (Make sure to set options('scipen'=99) so it doesn't render in scientific notation)

Comment: It is worth reminding folks that  the [int64 package is no longer maintained](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/index.html) and has been off CRAN for over 2 1/2 years.

Answer (score 4):

You simply cannot represent integers that big. See

```
.Machine
```

which on my box has

```
$integer.max
[1] 2147483647
```

Comment: This is very wrong, please delete or correct it. You can't represent these 64-bit integers as 32-bit integers. So you use a 64-bit integer library.

Comment: That is simply not how R works which only has 32-bit integers, hence my (still correct) answer. Your wishing for 64-bit integers does not add them to the interpreter / the language.

Comment: Dirk, that's incorrect and very rude as well. R had [packages implementing 64-bit integers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/int64-64-bit-integer-vectors-for-r/) **five years ago**. Whether the R core committee has gotten its act together on supporting them as a native type in the interpreter yet or not, is not our issue. The unqualified term 'integer' is not synonymous with '32-bit' - it could mean 64-bit, 128-bit etc. For heaven's sake, [C implemented uint64/int64 decades ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013245/are-types-like-uint32-int32-uint64-int64-defined-in-any-stdlib-header)

Comment: R != R packages. I am aware of the (abandoned) `int64` and (not widely used) `bit64` packages, but they do NOT solve the problem.  You plainly misunderstand what R does internally, and your references to other languages / system are (while true in a narrow sense) simply inapplicable to the question. You just do not understand how R is implemented: `integer` *exactly* means 32bit here.  Making my answer still correct, and your downvote rude. For reference, also see the other answers here saying (effectively) the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer is 2,147,483,647.  Your numbers are much larger.

Try importing them as floating point values instead.

There4 are a few caveats to be aware of when dealing with floating point arithmetic in R or any other language:

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/floatingpoint-errors-explained.html

http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/03/when-is-a-zero-not-a-zero.html

http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. Try it yourself `a <- read.csv('temp.csv', colClasses = 'numeric', header=FALSE)` then `print(a, digits=20)` still has the same results @Zubin reports.