# Reading a CSV file containing longs?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird error in R when importing integer with many digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441035/weird-error-in-r-when-importing-integer-with-many-digits)

I have a CSV file containing longs (long integers) in one of the columns. How do I read this into R? When I do it the default way with just `read.csv`, the longs seem to get corrupted.

Comment: What do you mean they get corrupted?  How do you know they are corrupted?

Comment: Possibly related / duplicate of [Weird error in R when importing integer with many digits](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11441035/271616).

Comment: I think the link @JoshuaUlrich gave is more than "possibly related." I think it's your answer