# As..character changes extreme large numbers in R

Tags: r, character, largenumber

Dear stackoverflow community,
I work with a dataset with very large numbers, which represent customer id's. 
If I want to change these from string to as.character the following happens:

```
alpha<-"2510607126325391401"
beta<-as.numeric(alpha)
print(beta, digits=22)
[1] 2510607126325391360.000
```

Which is clearly not identical, does somebody now how to resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance,
Best,
Alec Minnema

Comment: It is not clear what you are wanting to do. Are you wanting to keep them as strings or do numerical calculations on them?

Comment: Do you want to change them from string to numeric? The string is already character.

Comment: If it's a customer ID, sounds like it would be better to keep it as a character. R numeric values do not have the precision to hold that many digits for an integer.

Comment: First check str(alpha), and find if it is chr or num in the first place. Those are indeed character at the beginning

Comment: Possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441035/weird-error-in-r-when-importing-integer-with-many-digits/11441427#11441427

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that it may not be a good idea to represent customer id's in a numeric value, you can use the class `bigz` from package `gmp`:

```
require(gmp)
alpha<-"2510607126325391401"
as.bigz(alpha)
```