# command int cannot calculate large number ?

Tags: c, int

i wanted to find largest prime factor of 600851475143, and i wrote a code that can calculate prime factor of 13195 or less numbers. but my code cannot calculate 600851475143 this numbers largest prime factor why is that ? 
here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main( ){

    int n, a, b;
    printf( "enter a number=> " );
    scanf( "%d", &n );
    for ( a = n; a >= 2; a-- ){
        for ( b = 2; b <= a; b++ ){
            if ( a % b == 0 ){break;}
            else if ( b == a - 1 ){
             if( n % a == 0 ){
             printf("here is the largest prime number => %d\n", a);
                return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that there is no limit to how big a number can be expressed as an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `600851475143` is too big to hold for `int` data type.
Use `long long` instead of `int`.So,change the following lines in your code to this:

```
long long n, a, b;

scanf( "%lld", &n );

printf("here is the largest prime number => %lld\n", a);
```

Checkout the link for details : [Range of values in C Int and Long 32 - 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155784/range-of-values-in-c-int-and-long-32-64-bits)

Comment: yea it seems working but my algorithm seems bad, it will take almost 1 weak to calculate  :)thanks

Answer (score 0):

That value is larger than the maximum value of the int data type.  You will likely need a 64 bit INT value.

[Are types like uint32, int32, uint64, int64 defined in any stdlib header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013245/are-types-like-uint32-int32-uint64-int64-defined-in-any-stdlib-header)